# What is the CORE:match (opcode) subroutine in Perl profiling?

Tags: perl, profiling, subroutine

I previously wrote some utilities in Perl, and I am now rewriting them in order to give some new/better features. However, things seem to be going much more slowly than in the original utilities, so I decided to run one with the NYTProf profiler. Great profiler btw, still trying to figure out all its useful features.

So anyway, it turns out that 93% of my program's time is being spent on calls to the `GeneModel::CORE:match (opcode)` subroutine, and I have *no* idea what this is. Most Google hits point to NYTProf profiles others have posted. I indeed wrote the `GeneModel` class/package, but I don't know what this subroutine is, why it was called so many times, or why it's taking so long. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`CORE:match` is a call to a regular expression -- in this case, within your `GeneModel` package.

For example, if we profile this script, [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::NYTProf) reports 1000 calls to `Foo::CORE:match`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Foo;
my $s = 'foo foo';
$s =~ /foo/ for 1 .. 1000;
```

Answer (score 7):

Perl is compiled to opcodes. The [`m`atch operator](http://p3rl.org/op#%2fPATTERN%2fmsixpogc) results in a match opcode.

```
> perl -MO=Terse -e'm//'
LISTOP (0x8c4b40) leave [1]
    OP (0x8c4070) enter
    COP (0x8c4780) nextstate
    PMOP (0x8c4260) match
```

This is not a subroutine, but merely represented that way as opcode profiling is a recent addition and the UI hasn't been overhauled yet to take that into account. In simple words, the profiler is telling you that most time is spent in the regex engine.